# Black subview as picker view

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, subview

I'm having some problems while popping up a picker view when clicking into a textfield. It's correctly popped (and keyboard is properly hidden), but instead of showing my array of data, it pops up as a black subview... any similar experience? any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont make connection for datasource and delegate methods of picker view check those and implement

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView




- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Comment: You may be right, I've implemented those functions you mention, but I'm not sure if I've made the right conections... I can't test it now, but I'll check it later.. thank you very much!

Comment: @GDel if this solves your problem when you have checked then plz accept the ans

Comment: Thank you again! I've checked it and I had missed a "pickerView.delegate = self;" instruction. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Is the pickerView at all isn't visible? Or only data is missing?
Are you setting frame of pickerView? You should not tweak with its height. Its height should be default one. You can get that value from IB.

Comment: The whole pickerView appears as a black subview, and yes, I'm setting its frame this way: "pickerView2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, b, 325, 250)];" where b is a variable which takes a different value depending on the textfield pushed, so I don't "play" with its heigth...